# Como hago para iterar con un array

Tags: php, ajax, json, array

Como hago para iterar con un `array` que me traigo desde la base de datos en php para luego enviar todos esos datos obtenidos por un `JSON` hacia mi vista?

Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora:

```
$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
$errores = array();

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    echo 'false';
}else{
    $razas = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM razas ORDER BY nombre ASC");
    if ($razas->num_rows > 0) {
        $datos = $razas->fetch_assoc();

        $longitud = count($datos);

    }

}
```

Lo que quiero es recorrer el arreglo que trae dos campos desde la base de datos... Que se traiga todo lo de la tabla y pasarlo por `JSON` a la vista y convertirlos en tag de `<option>` para un selector.

Comment: `json_encode($datos);` ¿Es esto lo que buscas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes intentar haciendo lo siguiente:

```
if ($razas->num_rows > 0) {
     $datos = $razas->fetch_assoc();
     foreach ($datos as $key => $value) {
        $newarray[$key] = $value;   
    }
}
```

De esta manera puedes tomar los valores del arreglo y pasarlo a otro.

Comment: Lo correcto seria hacer `while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {`, debido a que [`fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php), solo devuelve _una fila obtenida del conjunto de resultados_

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, actualizaré mi comentario.